# Creating responsive rows and columns INSIDE a CSS GRID layout

Tags: css, css-grid

I just made my first `CSS grid` layout and I am impressed by the way the template area's work, but at this moment in time I am also massively confused about the way I am suppose to fill the template area's with items that in itself have responsive columns.

For example. My template area named `content` contains a article tag with 1 row and 2 columns with responsive `Flexboxgrid/Bootstrapgrid` behaviour. Like so:

```
<main class="g-content">
       <article>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                   column left
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                    column right
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
</main>
```

And CSS, where `g-content` is just a grid-area:

```
<style>
    .g-content {
      grid-area: content;
    }
</style>
```

I love the flexibility that these `col-` classes give, because they are in the html. So I add 2 classes in this case and the column behaves like I want it to.

So I'm not concerned with the overall template anymore, but I am concerned with the content blocks themselves... Now I throw out the idea of Flexboxgrid/Bootstrapgrid.

**So, what would be a fast and flexible way to, in this case, create 2 responsive columns using CSS Grid, that behave differently on certain breakpoints?**

Or isn't CSS Grid able to replace the Flexboxgrid/bootstrap responsive column system?

**Update:**
I am considering rewriting the bootstrap column classes but on a CSS GRID way. Not sure if this is the ultimate solution, but it works.

```
@include screen('sm') {
  .row-sm-4 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.row-sm-6 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
 }
}

@include screen('md') {
  .row-md-4 {
     display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
}
```

Ofcourse the col- classes need to become row- classes because the grid is apply from the container.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: I use Flexboxgrid. Same principle I guess.

Answer (score 2):

If you are already using CSS grid, why don't you just stick to it?

I would recommend not to mix more layout mechanisms and just stick to grid.

Till we don't have **css subgrid** available for all browsers, we cannot share same grid areas between childs, but we can control all our grids as independient grids.

A possible solution would be:

```
<main class="g-content">
<article>
  <div class="inner-grid">
    <div class="inner-cell">
      column left
    </div>
    <div class="inner-cell">
      column right
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
</main>
```

And now, via CSS:

```
@media (min-width: [SM BREAKPOINT] {
  .inner-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gutter: GUTTER;
  }
}
```

Note that, as in smaller resolutions your layout is just rows, you only need to apply style when you are **above** SM breakpoint.

As an alternative, you can also archieve this via flex:

```
@media (min-width: [SM BREAKPOINT] {
  .inner-grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
  }
  .inner-cell {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
  }
}
```

In general:

- For modern browser support, use CSS native grid or flex.
- Try not to mix frameworks with different methodologies.
- Use flex for alignment (like in your example).
- Use grid to create grids (duh).

Comment: Thanks you this was very informative. Would it be a good idea for me to rewrite the .row and .col- classes used in bootstrap but in the CSS GRID way? I think that in that way I stick to the CSS GRID way but keep the brilliance of the bootstrap-grid classes.

Comment: Use whatever suits your needs :) Personally, I won't go back to use a framework for layouts, since we do have grids spec now, which is way more powerful than any of this frameworks will ever be.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap, but I think it is better if you use flexbox css inside your grid content. And change the direction of flexbox depending on the breakpoints of media queries.